# Failed to flush state store

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

I'm trying to create a leftJoin in Kafka Streams which works fine for about 10 Records and then it crashes with an exception caused by a `NullPointerException` with such code:

```java
private static KafkaStreams getKafkaStreams() {
    StreamsConfig streamsConfig = new StreamsConfig(getProperties());
    KStreamBuilder builder = new KStreamBuilder();

    KTable<String, Verkaeufer> umsatzTable = builder.table(Serdes.String(), EventstreamSerde.Verkaeufer(), CommonUtilsConstants.TOPIC_VERKAEUFER_STAMMDATEN);
    KStream<String, String> verkaeuferStream = builder.stream(CommonUtilsConstants.TOPIC_ANZAHL_UMSATZ_PER_VERKAEUFER);

    KStream<String, String> tuttiStream = verkaeuferStream.leftJoin(umsatzTable,
            (tutti, verkaeufer) -> ("Vorname=" + verkaeufer.getVorname().toString() +",Nachname=" +verkaeufer.getNachname().toString() +"," +tutti.toString()), Serdes.String(), Serdes.String());

    tuttiStream.to(Serdes.String(), Serdes.String(), CommonUtilsConstants.TOPIC_TUTTI);

    return new KafkaStreams(builder, streamsConfig);
}
```

`StreamsConfig` looks like this:

```java
private static Properties getProperties() {
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put(StreamsConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, CommonUtilsConstants.BOOTSTRAP_SERVER_CONFIGURATION);
    props.put(StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG, CommonUtilsConstants.GID_TUTTI);
    props.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_KEY_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass());
    props.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_VALUE_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG,Serdes.String().getClass());
    props.put(StreamsConfig.CACHE_MAX_BYTES_BUFFERING_CONFIG, "1000");

    return props;
}
```

Full Stack Trace:

```
22:19:36.550 [gid-tutti-8fe6be58-d5c5-41ce-982d-88081b98004e-StreamThread-1] ERROR o.a.k.s.p.internals.StreamThread - stream-thread [gid-tutti-8fe6be58-d5c5-41ce-982d-88081b98004e-StreamThread-1] Failed to commit StreamTask 0_0 state: org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.ProcessorStateException: task [0_0] Failed to flush state store KTABLE-SOURCE-STATE-STORE-0000000000
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorStateManager.flush(ProcessorStateManager.java:262)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.AbstractTask.flushState(AbstractTask.java:190)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamTask.flushState(StreamTask.java:282)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamTask$1.run(StreamTask.java:264)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamsMetricsImpl.measureLatencyNs(StreamsMetricsImpl.java:187)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamTask.commitImpl(StreamTask.java:259)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamTask.commit(StreamTask.java:253)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.commitOne(StreamThread.java:815)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.access$2800(StreamThread.java:73)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread$2.apply(StreamThread.java:797)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.performOnStreamTasks(StreamThread.java:1448)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.commitAll(StreamThread.java:789)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.maybeCommit(StreamThread.java:778)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runLoop(StreamThread.java:567)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.run(StreamThread.java:527) Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
at java.lang.String.<init>(String.java:143)
at ch.wesr.eventstream.commonutils.serde.GsonDeserializer.deserialize(GsonDeserializer.java:38)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.StateSerdes.valueFrom(StateSerdes.java:163)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.CachingKeyValueStore.putAndMaybeForward(CachingKeyValueStore.java:90)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.CachingKeyValueStore.access$000(CachingKeyValueStore.java:34)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.CachingKeyValueStore$1.apply(CachingKeyValueStore.java:78)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.NamedCache.flush(NamedCache.java:145)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.NamedCache.flush(NamedCache.java:103)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.ThreadCache.flush(ThreadCache.java:97)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.CachingKeyValueStore.flush(CachingKeyValueStore.java:107)
at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorStateManager.flush(ProcessorStateManager.java:260)
... 14 common frames omitted
```

**Update:**

This is what `GsonDeserialize` looks like

```java
public class GsonDeserializer<T> implements Deserializer<T>{

    public static final String CONFIG_VALUE_CLASS = "default.value.deserializer.class";
    public static final String CONFIG_KEY_CLASS = "default.key.deserializer.class";
    private Class<T> deserializedClass;
    private Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();

    public GsonDeserializer() {}

    @Override
    public void configure(Map<String, ?> config, boolean isKey) {
        String configKey = isKey ? CONFIG_KEY_CLASS : CONFIG_VALUE_CLASS;
        String clsName = String.valueOf(config.get(configKey));
        try {
            if (deserializedClass == null) {
                deserializedClass = (Class<T>) Class.forName(clsName);
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            System.err.printf("Failed to configure GsonDeserializer. " +
                            "Did you forget to specify the '%s' property ?%n",
                    configKey);
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public T deserialize(String s, byte[] bytes) {
        return gson.fromJson(new String(bytes), deserializedClass);
    }

    @Override
    public void close() {}
}
```

Comment: It seems the exception originate from your own code: `at ch.wesr.eventstream.commonutils.serde.GsonDeserializer.deserialize(GsonDeserializer.java:38)` -- can you double check there?

Comment: GsonDeserializer is in use in several other stream apps and there it works well and in my code for some records  10) works well and then it crashes. And if I raise StreamsConfig.CACHE-MAX_BYTES_BUFFERING_CONFIG to 10000 it works for about 100 Records

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As long as the cache is not flushed, your deserializer is never called. That's why it doesn't fail in the beginning and you can increase the time until it fails via cache size parameter and commit interval (we flush on commit).

Looking at your code for `GsonDeserializer`, it seems that `new String(bytes)` fails with NPE -- `String` constructor cannot take `null` as parameter -- your deserializer code must guard against `bytes==null` and should return `null` for this case directly.

Comment: @user7327392: If it works now, you should also "accept" the answer.